# SQL Error: ORA-00902: invalid datatype 00902. 00000 - "invalid datatype"

Tags: sql, oracle

```
CREATE TABLE DATA_LOCATION
(
DATA_LOCATION_ID INTEGER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1),
BRAND_NAME VARCHAR(15),
BUSINESS_UNIT_NAME VARCHAR(30),
BUSINESS_PROCESS_NAME VARCHAR(100),
LOCATION_NAME(30),
CONSTRAINT location_pk PRIMARY KEY (DATA_LOCATION_ID)
);
```

Not able to figure out where exactly i m missing it

Comment: `LOCATION_NAME(30)` doesn't look odd to you?

Comment: `LOCATION_NAME(30)` What's that type?

Comment: ohhh my bad how the hell did i miss it thank you    LOCATION_NAME varchar(30)

Comment: You should be using `varchar2` instead of `varchar`, incidentally. [See the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Data-Types.html#SQLRF-GUID-DF7E10FC-A461-4325-A295-3FD4D150809E).

Comment: @AlexPoole - I see that the documentation says `varchar` may be redefined to use different comparison semantics. Is this new? I though I read that `varchar` will be used to implement the SQL Standard treatment of empty strings (as different from `null`) - did I misread that? I wouldn't call that "different comparison semantics".

Comment: @mathguy - It's not new, it's had that phrase since at least 10g, and some form of the warning since at least 7 I think - I don't have my printed manuals to check any more. (The 'scheduled` part seems to have been left in there as a joke.) I think it is still only talking about comparison of null with empty strings though. Whether that counts as different comparison semantics is, er, semantics to some extent... I suppose they could argue its similar to the .blank-padded/nonpadded distinction, maybe. Anyway, the first sentence in that was the important part.

Comment: The "different comparison semantics" phrase [does go back to Oracle 7](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A57673_01/DOC/server/doc/SQL73/ch2.htm#index0076) *8-)

Comment: @AlexPoole - OK, thank you for clarifying. In that case (if it is still expected that `varchar` will be used for the standard-compliant treatment of NULL) I may rather use `varchar` as my datatype **intentionally** - I can't wait for Oracle to do the right thing (and for pigs to fly). In the very unlikely case that Oracle does implement the standard, I would rather not have to change all my `varchar2` to `varchar` just so I can take advantage of it. (Assuming, of course, that I would rather not have empty strings identified to `null`. I for one am strongly in that camp.)

Answer (score 0):

`LOCATION_NAME(30)` is missing a type.